# How can I simulate a basic drop shadow using border-image and linear-gradient?

Tags: html, css, border-image

I'd like to simulate a drop shadow effect using border-image and linear-gradient (for scroll performance reasons, I am not using the native box-shadow effect).

As can be seen in the example below and in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjsghk9t/), my attempted approach involves using border-image for the gradient, border-image-outset to move the shadow outside the content box, and border-width to show only the bottom edge.

Admittedly, I don't understand border-image so well, particularly when it comes to using it with linear-gradients. Through trial and error, I achieved what seemed to be a satisfactory result. But as it turns out, when the width of the div is short enough, the "shadow" disappears entirely.

What can I do to achieve a drop shadow like in the top box, but one that works regardless of the box size? Your help with this is really appreciated!

```css
.box
{
  /* the "shadow" */
  border-image:  linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 10%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%) 100 repeat;
    border-image-outset: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
    border-width: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
    border-style: solid; 
  
  /* other stuff */
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FEFEFE;
  background: #007277;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Here's longer text, where the "shadow" appears how I want it to.
</div>

<div class="box">
Short
</div>
```

Comment: Use box-shadow. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Comment: @pol Not using it for scroll performance reasons. I edited the description to better explain that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the short border to work you need to change the

```
100 repeat;
```

to

```
0 0 100 0 repeat;
```

```css
.box
{
  /* the "shadow" */
  border-image:  linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 10%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%) 0 0 100 0 repeat;
    border-image-outset: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
    border-width: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
    border-style: solid; 
  
  /* other stuff */
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FEFEFE;
  background: #007277;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Here's longer text, where the "shadow" appears how I want it to.
</div>

<div class="box">
Short
</div>
```

This link may help you a little on your border imaging https://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I'll educate myself better on border-image. What's a little confusing to me is how linear-gradient doesn't have an image size, so  what do the slice percentages refer to? Does the border-width determine the "image size" of the linear-gradient?

Comment: I did a little research and I believe the `border-image-width` is what determines the slice percentages. I found this other link to be the most helpful in understanding how `border-image` works. http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/border-image/